# EMV TLV parsing sometimes does not display constructed values (childs)

Tags: java, format, emv, tlv, ber

My method `parseTLV()` sometimes does not properly decend into constructed values (child TLVs). I use a filter `((tag & 0x20)! = 0)` to detect constructed values, but sometimes it doesn't work as expected.

For example

```
70178C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704
```

leads to the following result for `parseTLV`:

- Tag: `70` - Value: `8C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704`
- Tag: `8C` - Value: `9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704`

However, I would expect to get

- Tag: `70` - Value: `8C159F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704`
- Tag: `8C` - Value: `9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704`

  - Tag: `9F02` - Value: `06`
  - Tag: `9F03` - Value: `06`
  - Tag: `9F1A` - Value: `02`
  - Tag: `95` - Value: `05`
  - Tag: `5F2A` - Value: `02`
  - Tag: `9A` - Value: `03`
  - Tag: `9C` - Value: `01`
  - Tag: `9F37` - Value: `04`

```
private ITlv.ITlvDataObjList parseTLV(byte[] src) {
    try {
        if (isBytesEmpty(src)) {
            return null;
        }
        _tlvList = _tlv.createTlvDataObjectList();
        int start = 0;
        int end = start + src.length;
        while (start < end) {
            // tag has 1 byte (0xFF)
            int tag = src[start++] & 0xFF;
            //
            if (tag == 0x00 || tag == 0xFF) {
                continue;
            }
            // tag has more bytes?
            if ((tag & 0x1F) == 0x1F) {
                if (start >= src.length) {
                    break;
                }
                // tag has 2 bytes (0xFFFF)
                tag = (tag << 8) | src[start++] & 0xFF;
                // tag has 3 bytes (0xFFFFFF)
                if ((tag & 0x80) != 0) {
                    if (start >= src.length) {
                        break;
                    }
                    tag = (tag << 8) | src[start++] & 0xFF;
                }
                // break when tag > 3 bytes
                if ((tag & 0x80) != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // length 1 byte (0x7F)
            int length = src[start++] & 0xFF;
            // length has more bytes?
            if (length >= 0x80) {
                // break when length > 2 bytes 
                int count = length & 0x7F;
                if (count > 3) {
                    continue;
                }
                // length 1 bytes (0x80-0xFF) or 2 bytes (0x100-0xFFFF)
                length = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
                    if (start >= src.length) {
                        break;
                    }
                    length = (length << 8) | src[start++] & 0xFF;
                }
            }
            // values
            byte[] value = new byte[length];
            System.arraycopy(src, start, value, 0, length);
            //
            // create tlv object
            ITlv.ITlvDataObj tlvObj = _tlv.createTlvDataObject();
            tlvObj.setTag(tag);
            tlvObj.setValue(value);
            // save tlv object to list
            _tlvList.addDataObj(tlvObj);
            //
            // next tag
            while (tag > 0xFF) {
                tag = tag >> 8;
            }
            // is constructed (has child)?
            if ((tag & 0x20) != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            start = start + value.length;
        }
        return _tlvList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `8C` does not contain a constructed value. Consequently, your test for `((tag & 0x20) != 0)` fails correctly. Instead, that TLV contains a data object list as its value. When you look at the value `9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F3704`, you'll find that these are not complete TLV onbjects but only tags + lengths.

Consequently, you will have to find out based on the tag whether that TLV object contains a data object list. Then you can parse that list in a similar way to parsing complete TLV objects except that you skip the empty value field.

Answer (score 0):

If EMV standards are not completely adhered to, your code may fail for below common reasons

- Tags may be longer than two bytes( from the code, you are not processing tags more than two bytes. The chance of encountering is low however )
- Length may be more than a byte long( though commonly length comes in one byte).
- Any new tag introduced by EMV will fail if you try to compare the tags against a list( ignore this if you do not ).

EMV 4.3 Book 3, Annex B Rules for BER-TLV Data Objects sections B1, B2, B3 is the correct place to look for. If you follow this precisely, all the above can be avoided.

Comment: thanks sir,  my code support for tag with two bytes and length with two bytes.